# RegEx: Find Matches Excluding a Specific Phrase

Tags: regex

I have tried a few of the answers to similar questions, but none work for what I am trying to do.

I am trying to find text that matches a specific phrase (with wildcard), but excludes any that include a second phrase.

> *Correct:* John yawns.
>
> *Incorrect:* John opens his mouth wide and yawns.

Essentially, I want to match off "(Someone) yawns." but not off "(Someone) opens his mouth wide and yawns." So the "opens his mouth wide and" is the match for exclusion, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Sadly, I am working with a log parsing application so I do not know what language is being used.

Comment: This could be easily solved with two substring tests (depending on which language you are using).

Comment: Added info about the language in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a negative lookbehind, as in `(?<!opens his mouth wide and )yawns`. Beware that these can slow down the regex matching algorithm, and are not available everywhere.

You really should reduce your test-case to simple patterns (e.g. .*bc but not abc)

Comment: Beware however that not all dialects have support for lookbehind -- and in particular JavaScript (aka ECMA 262) regexes don't support them.

Comment: @fge: exactly. When asking regex questions it's good to specify the environment.

Comment: I haven't been able to fully test it, but I think this may have lead to a solution. I was able to get it to properly trigger on only the correct phrase by using (?<!opens\shis\smouth\swide\sand\s)yawns.$